# How do I upload a pdf to elasticsearch when using the elastic search java client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client

This [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.x/using-ingest-attachment.html) explains how to use the REST API to upload an attachment.

But I want to upload an attachment with the java client...

I assume the following classes are relevant (though I may be wrong)...

```
org.elasticsearch.ingest.IngestService
org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineStore
```

I realize that I can just fall back to the REST interface but I'd rather try and use the native client first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a BASE64 encoded PDF in a field like:

```
String base64;
try (InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToYourFile)) {
    byte bytes[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
}

IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "type", "id")
   .setPipeline("foo")
   .source(
       jsonBuilder().startObject()
           .field("field", base64)
       .endObject()
   );
```

In case you are not aware of it, I'm also linking to [FSCrawler project](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler) in case it solves something you want to do already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is four options that you can use to index PDFs to ElasticSearch

- Ingest Attachment Plugin
- Apache Tika
- FsCrawler
- Ambar

Pros/cons described in [this post](https://blog.ambar.cloud/ingesting-documents-pdf-word-txt-etc-into-elasticsearch/)